# Is Database Normalized Enough/Properly?

Tags: mysql, database, normalization

I had some really ugly tables in my database, and so I went back and tried to normalize it.  I am not sure if it is enough, or done properly, and would appreciate any suggestions on how to improve my database setup.

I have set it up at SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7ac6a1

Comment: Yes, it seems 'normalised enough', but you're missing PKs on some tables, and you've provided surrogate PKs on other tables (where natural keys exist). These aren't referenced in any other tables, making them (to my mind) redundant.

Comment: Which are you referring to?  I know tables like dragon_to_habitat, boosts, and dragon_elements don't have PKs since they take the PKs from other tables.    Which do you feel are redundant?

Comment: ALL tables in an RDBMS require PRIMARY KEYs. This is fundamental (1NF). On a linking table, a PRIMARY KEY can be formed from a composite of the FOREIGN KEYs to other tables.

Comment: @Strawberry There are no primary keys in relational theory. A PK is some candidate key (aka key) chosen... to call "primary key". Candidate keys matter. They are minimal superkeys. A superkey is a column with unique values. Which in SQL is one defined unique via UNIQUE or PK declarations. So in fact an SQL "PK" column set isn't even necessarily a key. But every table does have at least one key and its keys should be declared.

Comment: @philipxy That's great. My point is simply that all tables in an RDBMS should have a mechanism incorporated within them for uniquely identifying each row. Whether it's technically precise, I think we can agree that in common parlance this is referred to as the PRIMARY KEY.

Comment: @Strawberry Understand. But if a person does not share common parlance because they do not share common knowledge then using it cavalierly isn't going to help them. They need to be clearly informed or redirected. "Technically correct" is generally a euphemism for "clear (vs conveniently but unhelpfully unclear)".

Comment: @philipxy Oh, I don't agree with that at all. I take the Nietzschean view. We operate in error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added PKs for the tables that were lacking using both fields combined as the PK.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `boosts` (
  `habitat_list_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `element_id` int(5) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`habitat_list_id`,`element_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```